# How can I analyse my JS program to ensure a particular method is always called with 2 arguments?

Tags: javascript, static-analysis

We're using promises in an AngularJS project and want to ensure that the `then` method is always called with 2 arguments, the 2nd being an error handler, like so:

```
$http.get(url).then(function () {
  console.log('hooray!');
}, function (error) {
  console.log('boo! error');
});
```

We're using jshint on the project. Can that perform this analysis?

Some calls to `then` do not require an error handler, i.e. in a chain of handlers:

```
$http.get(url1).then(function () {
  console.log('hooray!');
  return $http.get(url2);
}).then(function () {
  console.log('hooray again! all our data loaded');
}, function (error) {
  console.log('boo! error in one of our 2 requests');
});
```

We could mark these up using jshint's `/* jshint ignore:start */` comments or similar.